# Receive sms Twilio Webhook

Tags: twilio

I'm new to Twilio and tried to follow the guide for setting up to send and receive SMS to a server hosted on Google cloud,

I installed the Twilio SDK and the outgoing messages were working good, but for incoming, I got stuck,

I tried to follow the steps from here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/tutorials/how-to-receive-and-reply-php
but couldn't figure it out.

I created this code replyToMessage.php

```
<?php
// Get the PHP helper library from https://twilio.com/docs/libraries/php

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php'; // Loads the library
use Twilio\Twiml;

$response = new Twiml;
$response->message("The Robots are coming! Head for the hills!");
print $response;
```

and then update the Webhook on Twilio to http://myServer/replyToMessage.php
[Twilio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XrHKU.png)

but when I tried to send a message it gets an error:

ERROR 11200 There was a failure attempting to retrieve the contents of this URL

DESCRIPTION
There was a failure attempting to retrieve the contents of this URL

When I tried to see if server listen to HTTP requests. I created a code test.php with that code:

```
<?php

echo 'Hello, How World';

?>
```

and tried to call from a browser http://MyServerIp/test.php It works good

Comment: In this case Twilio acts just like any HTTP client . Use cURL or Postman and make a POST request to your `http://myServer/replyToMessage.php`, what do you see?

Comment: Thanks Alex, 


Tried a post with Postman without passing in any Params, and didn't get back any response.

Comment: make sure you turn on error reporting (https://stackify.com/display-php-errors/)

Comment: Ok, I found what's going on, all posts going ONLY to the index.php, (maybe some setting somewhere) so I put the code there and it works good, anyway thanks Alex for your help.